# With RealURL, define a character to replace "/" in page title

Tags: typo3, realurl, typo3-4.5

With TYPO3 (currently 4.5) and RealURL, is it possible to define how the character "/" should be mapped, if it is used in a page title?

E.g. "Demand / Offer"

with my settings, translates to

```
/demandoffer
```

So white space is not translated, as well as the slash.

Is it possible to make this translate to

```
/demand-offer
```

?

Answer (score 2):

If no space in `Foo/Bar` it won't use the minus char, anyway you can use `Speaking URL path segment` field in page properties to set `foo-bar` path for `Foo/Bar` page title.

Answer (score 0):

I had that wrong.

The title entered didn't contain any white space around the slash.

It was "Demand/Offer".

When the Whitespace is added arround the slash, RealURL parses it nicely as "-".